# Como capturar o valor de datas com DatePicker

Tags: android, datapicker

Tenho um DatePicker em meu projeto e gostaria de saber como pegar o valor da data escolhida apos selecionala.

Sei que no calenderView se faz assim:

```
 calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer algo parecido com o DatePicker

Prints dos erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Basta utilizar [DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)

Comment: Não funciona, mostra como erro

Comment: Qual o erro aparece?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr vou anexar uns prints, fica melhor

Comment: @ValdeirPsr pronto, adicionei os prints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem necessidade de adicionar o `new`. Dessa forma estaria criando uma classe com a interface `DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener`.

O correto é você capturar através do `findViewById` ou similar e adicionar esse evento no método `setOnDateChangedListener`.

**Exemplo:**

```
DatePicker datePicker = findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

datePicker.setOnDateChangedListener(new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        System.out.println( String.format(Locale.CANADA, "%d/%d/%d", dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year) );
    }
});
```

Em versões inferior a 25, utilize o método `init`:

**Exemplo:**

```
DatePicker datePicker = findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

datePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        System.out.println( String.format(Locale.CANADA, "%d/%d/%d", dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year) );
    }
});
```

Comment: No primeiro exemplo mostra "cannot resolve method 'setOnDateChangedListener...'"

Comment: Vou testar o segundo agr

Comment: Ah, e sobre o new, foi sugestao do próprio android stuido devido ao erro, os prints seguem o erros em sequencia

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é usando a DatePicker do Android:

Crie uma classe que extenda `DialogFragment` e implemente a interface `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private Listener listener;

    public static DatePickerFragment getInstance(){
       return new DatePickerFragment();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        //TODO criar metodo para formatar data
        String date = year + " " + month + " " + day;

        if(listener != null){
            listener.onDatePicked(data);
        }
    }

    public interface Listener{
        void onDatePicked(String data);
    }

    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

E depois a use onde quiser:

```
DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = DatePickerFragment.getInstance();
datePickerFragment.setListener(new DatePickerFragment.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onDatePicked(String date) {
        //TODO fazer algo com a data retornada
    }
});
```